# How to let the user reuse a result from previous computation in a python calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, calculator

I am fairly new at python so I don't know much about it. I made a calculator and I want it to accept a:

```
ans()
```

input. Currently, there is a part that stops the program from executing an input if there is something other than [0-9 */-+] so it does not crash. How can I make

```
ans()
```

represent the output of the equation last entered so I can enter something like this:

```
>> 8*8 #last input
64 #last output
>> ans()*2 #current input
128 # current output
```

Hopefully I explained everything correctly and here is my code:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/* \n";
    while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        exec(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    else:
        print(x)
```

Update: I added several lines but it would not run:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/* \n";
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    def ans():
        return _
    def ans():
        try:
            return _
    except NameError:
        return 0 # appropriate value
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        exec(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    else:
        print(x)
```

Error: "Unexpected Indent" for except NameError

What did I do wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks

Update:

Alright, I fixed it:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/*ans() \n"
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    def ans():
        return z
    def ans():
        try:
            return z
    except NameError:
        return 0 # appropriate value
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        exec(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    else:
        z = x
        print(x)
```

Just added the

```
z = x
```

and change the "_" with z

Thanks!

Comment: Python is space sensitive. Make sure all your spaces and tabs match. That's what that error means.

Comment: ok, i will look into that

Comment: Look at this line `except NameError:`. That is where your error is. Except should line up with try. That solves the `Unexpected Indent` error.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Turns out  answer below answers this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def ans():
        try:
            return _
    except NameError:
        return 0 # appropriate value
```

Your try and except need to have the same indentation. Use it like this

```
def ans():
    try:
        return _
    except NameError:
        return 0 # appropriate value
```

Comment: This fixes the indent error but when I did ans()*8 after I entered 8*8, it gave me 0. How do I fix that?

Comment: Unless you're working in ipython or something similar. _ will not be the last output.

Comment: oh, I am using IDLE and v3.3.0 python OSX

Answer (score 1):

```
valid_chars = list("0123456789-+/* \n")
while True:
    x = "ans = "
    y = raw_input(" >> ")
    x += y
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y.replace('ans','')):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        exec(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    except NameError:
        if y == 'ans':
            print("ans undefined")
        else:
            raise
    else:
        print(ans)
```